# Angular interceptor 401 refresh token

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors, refresh-token

Ok, this should be an easy thing to solve, but because of how the app was previously designed it is a little more complicated. Most of the answers I find don't work out for the problem I am trying to solve.

Essentially, I intercept the API calls and when there is a 401 I want to get a new token. The way this app was designed, I have an async action I can call that kicks off the API call to get the new token. It then saves that token in localStorage. There is a flag in the store that tracks the progress of this process. So right now I have to listen to the observable and after it completes grab the new token from localStorage and then make the call again.

Something like this:

```
this.initRefreshFlag$.subscribe((val, i) => {
    if (val === InitFlagType.Done) {
        const newRequest = request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Authorization':
                `${localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_TYPE)} ${localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY)}`
            }
        });
        return next.handle(newRequest);
    }
});
```

However, the `next.handle()` doesn't fire. And I now understand that subscribe is not what I want to use here due to possible memory leaks. I tried using `switchMap` and `mergeMap` but they do not fire when the observable `this.initRefreshFlag$` changes.

I am at a loss on the best way to proceed here without refactoring a bunch of stuff in the actions/epics. Any suggestions?

Comment: How does your async action work? Looks like you need to pipe these two processes. After the new token is generated and stored in localStorage, interceptor should move on and continue the original request.

Comment: Take a look at how to implement HTTP Interceptor : https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused what didn't work with `switchMap` or `mergeMap` but essentially you can't return anything from `subscribe()`.

In general if you want to execute one Observable, then use its value for something a continue with another Observable you can use `mergeMap`:

```
this.initRefreshFlag$.pipe(
  mergeMap(val => {
    const newRequest = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'Authorization': `${localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_TYPE)} ${localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY)}`
      }
    });

    return next.handle(newRequest);
  })
)
```

Comment: Ok, I have implemented this, essentially exactly as you have here. But none of the code within the mergeMap() actually runs. Any ideas there?